# Why does Spring-AOP pointcut work for save(..) but not saveAll(..)

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop, pointcut

I have a Spring-Data repository like this:

```
package com.example.demo;

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {

    @Override
    <S extends Foo> S save(S entity);

    @Override
    <S extends Foo> List<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities);

}
```

And an aspect like this:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class FooAspect {

    @Before("execution(* org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.save(*))")
    void crudSaveBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("crud save");
    }

    @Before("execution(* com.example.demo.FooRepository.save(*))")
    void fooSaveBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("foo save");
    }

    @Before("execution(* org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.saveAll(*))")
    void crudSaveAll(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("crud save all");
    }

    @Before("execution(* com.example.demo.FooRepository.saveAll(*))")
    void fooSaveAll(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("foo save all");
    }

}
```

When I run `fooRepository.save(..)`, in the console I see: `foo save`

When I run `fooRepository.saveAll(..)`, in the console I see `foo save all` and `crud save all`

I was expecting `saveAll` to only intercept on the `FooRepository` flavor since I am point-cutting the package.class.method directly. This seems to have worked for `save`, but not `saveAll`.

Is this because the args in `saveAll` are `Iterable`? Or some kind of type-erasure happening here with the generics? Something else?

Comment: I am pretty sure I could help you if I knew how to run this code. Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), ideally on GitHub. Then I will take a look. (I am a Spring noob, but kind of an AOP expert.)

Comment: Apparently you can combine pointcut expressions with logical operators AND, NOT, OR. That way, you could make the expressions in your @Before annotations stricter e.g. "Match FooRepo.saveAll but NOT CrudRepo.saveAll". See "Combining Pointcut Expressions" here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop-pointcut-tutorial

Comment: I answered your question, because as it turns out, it is an interesting case deserving an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

It seems AOP issue. For proxy `FooRepository.saveAll` it invokes `CrudRepository.saveAll` `@Before` expression:

`AbstractAspectJAdvice 683`
[image: AOP pointcut]

Comment: It is a type erasure issue, see my new answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am revisiting this question due to a similar topic that came up for me.

> I was expecting `saveAll` to only intercept on the `FooRepository` flavor since I am point-cutting the package.class.method directly. This seems to have worked for `save`, but not `saveAll`.

I am rather surprised that not all 4 pointcuts are matching. The puzzling question is, why this does **not** match:

```java
execution(* org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.save(*))
```

I already fond out, that this problem is not caused by Spring AOP as such, but also manifests itself in native AspectJ. There, the pointcut does not match either.

As a workaround, change the pointcut to use `+` to explicitly include subclasses or classes implementing interfaces:

```java
execution(* org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository+.save(*))
```

Now, all 4 pointcuts match, and this is also a clue as to why.

The fact that `+` helps, means that the AspectJ pointcut matcher correctly recognises that we are dealing with an interface method and also that `save` is inherited across a hierarchy. The difference to `saveAll` is type erasure. `saveAll` without generics looks like `List saveAll(Iterable)`, which is the same for the original interface, whereas for `save` it is more `Object save(Object)` in the interface vs. `Foo save(Foo)` in the implementing class. I.e., there the method signature does **not** directly match the interface's one, which is why we need to tell AspectJ to also check inheritance when matching.

This is not so much a bug in AspectJ, but rather subtlety in its usage with regard to generic types and type erasure. The fact that `saveAll` matches is just a "lucky chance", because there both in the return type and the method parameter we use specific types, and the generics only apply to type parameters of those types. In `save`, however, the generic types are used directly erasure-wise.

Disassembling the classes confirms what I explained above:

```java
public abstract interface org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository implements org/springframework/data/repository/Repository {
  // ...
  // signature <S:TT;>(TS;)TS;
  // declaration: S save<S extends T>(S)
  public abstract save(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
  // ...
  // signature <S:TT;>(Ljava/lang/Iterable<TS;>;)Ljava/lang/Iterable<TS;>;
  // declaration: java.lang.Iterable<S> saveAll<S extends T>(java.lang.Iterable<S>)
  public abstract saveAll(Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Ljava/lang/Iterable;
  // ...
}
```

```java
class FooRepositoryImpl implements FooRepository {
  // ...
  // signature <S:LFoo;>(TS;)TS;
  // declaration: S save<S extends Foo>(S)
  public save(LFoo;)LFoo;
  // ...
  // signature <S:LFoo;>(Ljava/lang/Iterable<TS;>;)Ljava/util/List<TS;>;
  // declaration: java.util.List<S> saveAll<S extends Foo>(java.lang.Iterable<S>)
  public saveAll(Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Ljava/util/List;
  // ...
}
```